# Nested JSON file from Php and Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am working on fetching JSON file from the database, which has two table **semone** with attributes **id, semester, cname** and table **courses** with attributes **coname and credit**.

Code I am writing in php is following.

**main.php**

```
<?php
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "scheduler";

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $database) or die ("Unable to connect"); 
    $query = "SELECT semone.userid AS id,  semone.semester AS semester, semone.cname AS name, courses.credit AS value
    FROM semone
    INNER JOIN courses
    ON semone.cname = courses.coname" ;

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die ("Unable to connect");

    $info = array();
    $test = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

          $row['xyz'] = array(
          'name'=> $row['name'],
          'value'=> $row['value']    
          );

    $info[$row['id']]['children'][$row['semester']]['children'][]= $row['xyz'];

    }
    $data = json_encode(($info));
    echo $data;
?>
```

I want to get JSON file as seen in the following code, but I am getting something like this.

**output.json**

```
{
    "12345": {
        "children": {
            "first": {
                "children": [{
                    "name": "C101",
                        "value": 100

                },

                {
                    "name": "C102",
                        "value": 100

                }]
            },

                "second": {
                "children": [{
                    "name": "C103",
                        "value": 50

                }, {
                    "name": "C104",
                        "value": 100

                }, {
                    "name": "C105",
                        "value": 100

                }]
            },

                "third": {
                "children": [{
                    "name": "C106",
                        "value": 50

                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is what I am expecting.

**expected.json**

```
{
 "id": 12345,
     "children": [{
     "semester": "first",
         "children": [{
         "name": "C101",
             "value": 100

     },

     {
         "name": "C102",
             "value": 100

     }]
 }, {
     "semester": "second",
         "children": [{
         "name": "C103",
             "value": 50

     }, {
         "name": "C104",
             "value": 100

     }, {
         "name": "C105",
             "value": 100

     }]
 }, {
     "semester": "third",
         "children": [{
         "name": "C106",
             "value": 50

     }]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should build your array in a different way:

```
$info[] = array(
    array('id' => $row['id']),
    'children' => array(
        'semester' => $row['semester'],
        'children' => $row['xyz']
    )
);
```

Comment: Its only giving the last element
{"0":{"id":"12345"},"children":{"semester":"third","children":[{"name":"CSE106","value":"50"}]}}

Comment: Becuase `$info` was overwritten each time, try to build `$info` As an array, look my edit

Comment: Even after editing id and semster are repeating every time, its not like , first semster have 2 course and then second one has 3 courses.

[{"0":{"id":"12345"},"children":{"semester":"first","children":[{"name":"CSE101","value":"100"}]}},{"0":{"id":"12345"},"children":{"semester":"first","children":[{"name":"CSE102","value":"100"}] and so on...
Semster should be only used three times and id to be used only once.. Hope you can see the difference